# Can you structure the include folder in a ROS C++ Package with subfolders?

Tags: ros, catkin, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I currently have some c++ libraries that i would like to implement and build in ROS using catkin workspaces.  My method so far has been to let each library be its own package, but I've recently run into a problem of circular dependencies with the packages. My approach to fix this has been to implement the libraries within a single package, but i somehow wish to keep the libraries separated and i therefore wonder if it is possible to structure the include folder for a ROS c++ package with subfolders?

The idea would look something like this

---

```
--my_package
  --include
    --library_1
      someheaderfile.h
    --library_2
      someotherheaderfile.h
        ..
  --src
    --library_1
      somecppfile.cpp
    --library_2
      someothercppfile.cpp
  CMakelists.txt
  package.xml
```

I guess my main concern lies within breaking the catkin structure needed for proper compilation.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/362936/can-you-structure-the-include-folder-in-a-ros-c++-package-with-subfolders?/) by [Paal](https://answers.ros.org/users/60512/paal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I guess my main concern lies within breaking the catkin structure needed for proper compilation.

there is no such structure.

Catkin ~= CMake.

> is [it] possible to structure the include folder for a ROS c++ package with subfolders?

yes, of course.

There is no magic here. It's all just regular C++ and CMake.

As long as you make sure everything which needs to be on the include path ends up there things will just work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1